# Grub is not loading the default kernel

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kernel, downgrade

I'm running Ubuntu 20.0.41 LTS with Kernel 5.8.0-36-generic and 5.4.0-42-generic installed. For installing ROCm i need to set the default boot Kernel to 5.4 to remove 5.8. After setting it as well in the grub file under default as in grub customizer as default grub still boots automatically into 5.8 instead of 5.4 as seen in the images
[5.4 selected as default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya7Ot.png)

[booted in 5.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpwFL.png)

even grub customizer didn't work
just for info, I installed grub in dual boot with windows

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1306572/167850 it explains how to remove the 5.8 kernel.