# Ubuntu kernel issue : have to choose older kernel to boot as new kernel does not work ( no network and graphics issues with new kernel)

Tags: drivers, kernel, graphics, ethernet

I have Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Desktop installed in my Lenovo Ideapad 320 Laptop and i had updated system few days back after restarting once finish the installed updates it booted ( kernel 5.8.0-34 generic) but with sluggish graphics and no network. So i tried few things but without network i couldn't do much so i restarted system and from grub advance options i choose older kernel ( 5.4.0-60 generic) and it worked without any issues. see image i have to choose 5.4 from this image to make ubuntu work without issues.[image: ubuntu grub]

I then tried again apt-get update and apt-get upgrade commands but no luck it does install all the packages but if i boot with 5.8 kernel it just doesn't boot with network. see attached image for ip addr command (no network interfaces at all) when i boot with 5.8 kernel [image: ip addr output]

Can anyone tell me what could be issue here. how do i fix this mess? as whenever i restart i have to press escape and load grub and from advance option choose 5.4 kernel.

Here is the current drivers info from additional drivers tab screen in ubuntu.

1. Realtek Semiconductor Corp : using dkms source for the r8812au network driver from r8812au-dkms(open source)
2. NVIDIA Corporation : GM108M [GeForce 940MX] - Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-450(proprietary)

Here is output of lshw -c video

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:5000(size=128)
```

dpkg -l output : https://pastebin.com/raw/QNktzj1g

Comment: The issue is that maintainers upgraded kernel and didn't upgrade everything else. You can revert to the 5.4 kernel. And stick with 5.4.0-xx kernels for a while. They will get updates.

Comment: hey @Pilot6 how do i that via commands ?

Comment: same problems here, with the wireless card, solved it with https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005058/dpkg-error-while-installation-bcmwl-kernel-source-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @GiorgosSaridakis both wireless and wired port also doesn't work. it doesn't even shown in ip addr command as well.

Comment: Hold on, I am writing the commands.

Comment: Only solution is to revert to the previous kernel (I suppose the next release will address these issues). @Pilot6 has given the best way around this below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the 5.8 kernel and stick with the `5.4.0-xx` kernels this way.

Boot with a 5.4 kernel using grub menu, then run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-5.8.0-36-generic linux-modules-5.8.0-36-generic linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-36-generic linux-headers-5.8.0-36-generic linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-36
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

Comment: I did this. it did uninstall but grub still boots on 5.8 and now its completely black. nothing happens. i then restarted the into 5.4 via grub and tried this command again but ubuntu says, "Package 'linux-headers-5.8.0-36-generic' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-36' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-5.8.0-36-generic' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-36-generic' is not installed, so not removed"

Comment: Some is wrong. The command should remove 5.8 completely. Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep linux` to your question. I'll see what was wrong. And I edited the command, added one package after the initial post.

Comment: added dpkg -l output as pastebin to question.

Comment: that was because of my initial mistake. Now run `sudo apt remove linux-modules-5.8.0-36-generic` and all will be fixed.

Comment: Yep It did work i had to run two commands though, sudo apt remove linux-modules-5.8.0-36-generic and sudo apt remove --purge linux-image-unsigned-5.8.0-36-generic
and then sudo update-grub

Comment: Thank you @Pilot6

Comment: OOps I forgot one more, thanks. No, the unsigned was installed because I forgot the "modules" one. I was too not very attentive.

Comment: Thanks for this @Pilot6 May I further ask: will this prevent future updates, locking the kernel at 5.4.x, or do we have to take specific action to prevent an unwanted kernel upgrade later? And if this prevents future updates from upgrading the kernel, a) will other patches be appropriate to the installed kernel and therefore safe? and b) what will we do to rejoin the normal flow of fixes when it's safe for us to do so? So many dependencies I don't understand :(

Comment: This won't "lock" anything. And this is a normal flow to use the 5.4 kernel for 20.04 LTS. Kenel will get updates till 2025. But anytime you can switch back to HWE by `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04`

Comment: Tip: You can use `apt list --installed | grep linux-image` and `apt list --installed | grep linux-modules` to see what kernels you have installed.